# does anyone know how I can setup a server to host my own private shop on the hidden service

Tags: onion-routing, server

I would like to open open my own shop with .onion extention but I'm stuck where to begin. Is there anyone who can give pointers or know if there is an extising guide from buying the server through to server coding and other softwhere pointers?
Should I use laravel or would it have to coding from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

Most of these questions are far too broad, but I'll do my best.

Setting an onion service is easy. You install the Tor service, tell it to use port 80, get your new onion address and start a web server.  That's easy.  [Here is the official guide](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-onion-service.html.en)

> if there is an extising guide from buying the server through to server
>   coding and other softwhere pointers?

There is probably not a guide written for that. The reason why is because most (though probably not all) people who set up stores on onion services tend to sell illegal things. You can image that people like that are not likely to advertise how they did it.

Your best bet is to take it slowly piece by piece. Create your first onion service on a home computer. Take time to read up on how to harden a web server and best practices for creating onion services. Don't expect an easy step 1, step 2, step 3 guide. If you want a successful onion service, it takes time, planning, and understanding.

> Should I use laravel or would it have to coding from scratch?

Is laravel a safe framework for building online stores in general?
Can it be security hardened?
You can use any programming language, framework, or platform that you want. It all depends on whether it is a good fit for what you want to do.

If you have any specific questions, there is a [tor-onions mailing list](https://lists.torproject.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/tor-onions/). Nobody will tell you step by step on how to do everything, but if you have specific questions it is a fantastic resource.

Comment: Appreciate your help, the server/computer is being shipped today so I'll start on it's arrival. Thanks @JSEvans, I followed many of your answers on here its much help.